# Spring social provider = ?error

Tags: java, spring-social

When i click on /signIn/facebook button it redirect me to facebook page i authorize and then it redirect me to my redirectUrl but with parametr error=provider. What i do wrong? As far as i know it shoud redirect to SignInAdapter and to compare userIds or something like this. How can i debug these. Why it's not working. My signInController should to redirect me to the signup page isn't it? here is my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true">

    <bean id="connectionFactoryLocator"
        class="org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry">
        <property name="connectionFactories">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory">
                    <constructor-arg value="${facebook.appId}" />
                    <constructor-arg value="${facebook.appSecret}" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="usersConnectionRepository"
        class="org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator" />
        <constructor-arg ref="textEncryptor" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="connectionRepository" factory-method="createConnectionRepository"
        factory-bean="usersConnectionRepository" scope="request">
        <constructor-arg value="guest" />
        <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController">
        <constructor-arg ref="simpleSignInAdapter" />
        <property name="applicationUrl" value="${application.url}" />
        <property name="signUpUrl" value="/signup" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="simpleSignInAdapter" class="com.social.SimpleSignInAdapter" />


    <bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController">
        <!-- relies on by-type autowiring for the constructor-args -->
        <property name="applicationUrl" value="${application.url}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="textEncryptor" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors"
        factory-method="noOpText" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Hi Igor, I am running into a similar issue. Were you able to find a solution to your problem? If so can you please share it?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11740105/923560

Comment: Find my answers to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583069/spring-social-project-not-running/39396772#39396772). It might be helpful to you.