# Spring Social - 404 error for facebook login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, facebook-oauth, spring-social

I have spring 3.1 with spring security login in my app. I am trying to add facebook login using spring social to it. 
It goes to the facebook login page but post log in it throws a 404 error. I have this in the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/TestProject/signin?error=provider#_=_
```

Here goes my spring social config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController">
<!-- relies on by-type autowiring for the constructor-args -->    
<constructor-arg ref="signInAdapter" />
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactoryLocator" 
  class="org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry">
<property name="connectionFactories">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory">
            <constructor-arg value="${fb.id}" />
            <constructor-arg value="${fb.passwrd}" />               
        </bean>
    </list>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="connectionRepository" factory-method="createConnectionRepository" 
  factory-bean="usersConnectionRepository" scope="request">
<constructor-arg value="#{request.userPrincipal.name}" />
<aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="signInAdapter" class="com.Test.social.SimpleSignInAdapter"/>

<bean id="usersConnectionRepository" 
  class="org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository">
<constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
<constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator" />
<constructor-arg ref="textEncryptor" />
</bean>

<bean id="textEncryptor" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors" 
        factory-method="noOpText" />
 </beans>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I too just suddently happened to get a redirect to `signin?error=provider#_=_`.

The reason was that just before this "error message" repeatedly happened, I updated my local JDK installation. With this new JDK installation, also any changes to my Java installation security settings were resetted to "fresh installation defaults". In particular, my manually installed [***UnlimitedJCEPolicy***](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) was no longer available. ***Reinstalling the UnlimitedJCEPolicy solved the problem in my case***.

In my particular case, I'm not using a `noOpText() TextEncryptor`, but a `queryableText(..) TextEncryptor`.

Comment: For me it was some issue with the app Id.. :) Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

What spring social version you are using? (must be 1.0.X)

Did you create a facebook application? (you need to provide application key/secret in FacebookConnectionFactory constructor). It seems you are using your facebook user/password.

Comment: and yes, i am using spring social 1.0.2.

Comment: Configuration looks ok.. Can you share what you seen in logs.

Comment: I think it was a appid, key copy paste issue..!! My bad.. its working fine now :)