# Spring Social project not running

Tags: java, spring, spring-social

I downloaded the Spring social project from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-quickstart

When I run the project on Tomcat, after asking for connection and connecting to facebook, the webpage automatically redirects to 
[http://localhost:8080/spring-social-quickstart/signin?error=provider#*=*](http://localhost:8080/spring-social-quickstart/signin?error=provider#_=_)

I am unable to understand the error. can anyone help?

//After Debugging
It is never executing the method in HomeController.java which extracts the friends and return the next page.

Comment: What is the error you are getting in logs?

Comment: There is no error related to this.

Comment: After Debugging It is never executing the method in HomeController.java which extracts the friends and return the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Check the followings:

1. Most probably you are disconnected from Internet. So check your network connectivity.
2. Ensure you have given correct **username** and **password** while connecting to facebook.
3. **Client Id** and **secret** (generally in XML or properties file, you get it when you create your application in facebook / twitter) you use are correct.
4. Make sure that you have defined a **callback url** while creating application in facebook / twitter.